# MySQL hangs forever on "rehash" command

Tags: mysql, hash, autocomplete, freeze

We have a MySQL server running with several databases in it, for different types of data. One of them is a wordpress database.

I can connect ok, "show databases", and "use apples", "use oranges" etc (substitute fruits for our actual databases) but when I do "use wordpress", instead of "database changed", I get

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
```

Sure enough, if I start mysql with an extra -A flag everything seems to work. Then I can "use wordpress" and look at the data.

If I start it with -A and do "use wordpress" it works, then I do "rehash" and it hangs.

Has anybody seen this? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL command line client offers database/table/column name completion: that is, when you start typing a name and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the name is completed. To do this, the client builds a hash of database, table and column names that it queries when you invoke completion.

If the command line client is started with [auto-rehashing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_auto-rehash) enabled, it automatically builds the completion hash when you connect to the database, and keeps it up-to-date. For large databases, this can take some time. When starting the client with `--no-auto-rehash` (`-A`), the hash is not built, and completion is not available until you manually build the hash (using `rehash` or `\#`). This decreases startup time, especially for large databases.

So, it's normal for the hashing to take quite a while on a large database. That's what you seem to be experiencing when you start with auto-rehashing enabled (i.e. either without `-A`, or with `-A` and then `rehash`). For small databases (`apples` and `oranges` in your example) it's not noticeable, but for large ones (`wordpress`) it's slow. Some alternatives I use:

- don't rehash
- get a coffee while the hash is building
- use a different client that offers completion quicker

Comment: I can add to that list of alternatives - Google around why it's taking forever and come across this question :)